# Why do create table and create function need different privileges

Tags: hive

I am reading Hive Authorization at

`https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-PrivilegesRequiredforHiveOperations`

I noticed:

1. create table needs the `database'owner` privileges
2. create function needs the `admin` privileges

I don't understand, why `create table` and `create function` need different privileges? the table and the function are two objects belonging to a database, that is to say, I think `create function` should be the same as `create table`, just needs the database'owner privileges, not admin privileges.

Could someone help explain?

Comment: Your function can access different tables. That's why it needs admin access.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you @Justinas